# Subtracting two column on group by same table SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table

```
create table events 
(
      event_type integer not null,
      value integer not null,
      time timestamp not null,
      unique(event_type, time)
);
```

I want to write a SQL query that, for each that has been registered more than once, returns the difference between the latest (i.e. the most recent in terms of) and the second latest. The table should be ordered by  (in ascending order).

Sample data is:

```
 event_type   | value      | time
 -------------+------------+--------------------
   2          |  5         | 2015-05-09 12:42:00
   4          | -42        | 2015-05-09 13:19:57
   2          |  2         | 2015-05-09 14:48:30
   2          |  7         | 2015-05-09 12:54:39
   3          | 16         | 2015-05-09 13:19:57
   3          | 20         | 2015-05-09 15:01:09
```

The output should be

```
   event_type | value
  ------------+-----------
   2          | -5
   3          | 4
```

So far I tried doing this

```
SELECT event_type  
FROM events 
GROUP BY event_type
HAVING COUNT(event_type) > 1 
ORDER BY event_type
```

I cannot find a way two get the right value for the second column that I've mentioned. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: what is your dbms? like Oracle,MySQL,Postgres,SQL Server..?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala sorry im using PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it using `lead`, which gets the next value of a given column based on a specified ordering. The *penultimate row* for a given event_type will have the latest value which can be used for subtraction in this case. (Run the inner query to see how the `next_val` is assigned)

```
select event_type,next_val-value as diff
from (select t.*
      ,lead(value) over(partition by event_type order by time) as next_val, 
      ,row_number() over(partition by event_type order by time desc) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t 
where next_val is not null and rnum=2
```

One more option with `DISTINCT ON` and `lead`.

```
select distinct on (event_type) event_type,next_val-value as diff
from (select t.*,lead(value) over(partition by event_type order by time) as next_val 
      from events t
     ) t 
where next_val is not null 
order by event_type,time desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ANSI/ISO standard window functions:

```
select event_type,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then value
                when seqnum = 2 then - value
           end) as diff_latest
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by event_type order by time desc) as seqnum
      from events e
     ) e
where seqnum in (1, 2)
group by event_type
having count(*) = 2;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/845e4/15) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: thank for this answer the result of this query is 
+---+-----+
| 2 |   2 |
| 3 |  20 |
| 4 | -42 |
+---+-----+

Comment: @bRaNdOn . . . I added a `having` condition to ensure that there are two rows.  The SQL Fiddle shows it working.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hi im currently aming for this result 2 = -5 and 3 = 4 since we subtract the latest two numbers based on dates thanks a lot for this effort

Comment: @bRaNdOn . . . That should be (and is) `sum()` rather than `max()`.